# How to authenticate a user using django rest framework

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, python-3.x, django

I am trying to `authenticate` a user using **django rest framework** and `authenticate` import below but for some reason i keep getting `null` as a result when i check the front end with `reactJS`, i am referring to the variable `logged_in_used` below:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

...

if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.data.get('username')
        password = request.data.get('password')

        get_user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        logged_in_used = authenticate(username=get_user.username, password=get_user.check_password(password))

         ...
         # data with token dictionnary
         ...

         result = (data_with_token, logged_in_used, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Is there something that i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

try it like this

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

...

if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']

    logged_user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

    if logged_user is not None:
        login(request, logged_user)
```

from here you can redirect or whatever else :)

Comment: not working buddy

Comment: hmm, might have gotten excited with the Django part of it. If you are using JWTs the DRF developers recommend https://github.com/jazzband/djangorestframework-simplejwt so that might be worth a gander. I'm still familiarizing myself with React